# How to modify a single test case in manual recording using MTM

Tags: testing, automation, manual, microsoft-test-manager

I have created Testcase and record it also. Now i need to modify the test case.
If I do modification even of a single step, then next time if I want execute it, MTM is asking to again record the complete test case. Is it possible to modify single step?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Fast Forward feature, then this is the expected behavior. Any changes to the test will require you to record the steps again.